# Embed Cordova-Webview and Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to embed Cordova in my native iOS application. I only need a tiny part of my application to use cordova. From now I managed to show a CordovaViewController with some HTML in there, but I can't find out how to add cordova plugins (ex. cordova-plugin-network-information) in the project.

I installed it using cocoapods, but I can't find in the Cordova's documentation how to wire it up with my www folder so that navigator.connection would not be `undefined`

Thank you for your help!